# Count distinct and return a value with a max date

Tags: sql-server

I have something like:

```
Date                   ID  val 
2000-01-01 11:30:55.00 1   2   
2000-01-01 11:31:01.00 1   2   
2000-01-01 11:31:50.00 1   2   
2000-01-01 11:32:50.00 2   1   
2000-01-01 11:34:50.00 2   1   
2000-01-01 11:36:50.00 3   2   
2000-01-01 11:38:50.00 3   1
```

is there a way to return a `want` column, where I take the value assoc with max date grouped by the `ID`? Like so:

```
Date                   ID  val want
2000-01-01 11:30:55.00 1   2   NULL
2000-01-01 11:31:01.00 1   2   NULL
2000-01-01 11:31:50.00 1   2   2
2000-01-01 11:32:50.00 2   1   NULL
2000-01-01 11:34:50.00 2   1   1
2000-01-01 11:38:50.00 3   2   2
2000-01-01 11:36:50.00 3   1   NULL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select myTable.* 
from myTable
inner join 
(select id, max([date]) as maxDate
from myTable
group by id) tmp on myTable.id = tmp.Id 
where myTable.[date] = tmp.maxDate;
```

[DbFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=360b6d87544abde94df6d33775938520)

I am not sure if your edited question meant this:

```
select myTable.*,
 case when mytable.[date] = tmp.maxDate then val end as want
from myTable
left join (
select id, max([date]) as maxDate
from myTable
group by id) tmp on myTable.id = tmp.Id;
```

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=39be317e7eacdaf5c17ede7256e7c570)

Comment: @biostatguy12, I didn't understand the relation to NULL in want. You wanted to get the row with the latest date per ID, no? It does that. Adding fiddle demo.

Comment: it does which is great, but I need the nulls to remain (need to keep the earlier dates too but don't want values associated with them). I was thinking group by id, a count distinct by id, if gt 1 and max date then want=val, else NULL, if count distinct==1 then want=val. But I don't know how to do this

Comment: @biostatguy12, sorry but I don't understand what you want. Would you please edit your question to show what you mean (sample output you expect from that data).

Comment: my data is Date, Id, val. I want my output to be exactly like ```want```

Comment: @biostatguy12, it is simply not understandable, would you please edit your question and add the expected output there.

Comment: Is that it? :) Select * from myTable BTW you had want in your original query, where did it go?

Comment: yes, sorry if still confusing. Can you let me know if it is clear yet?

Comment: No it is not clear. Do you mean to mark latest date in a new column>

Comment: i added more examples. Hope it helps

Comment: @biostatguy12, OK your edited version has nothing to do with the original question, hope I got that right. Check the edited version.